# Selecting distinct dates for a blog archive

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, cucumber

I'm using Rails for a blog engine. I'm implementing an archive feature that archives based on unique month and years where a post has been published.

Here's the cucumber feature:

```
  Scenario: Displaying an archive menu from distinct posts months and years 
   Given the following posts exists for the blog "Blondinbella":
         | Title           | Published at          |
         | Redbull         | 1 March 2010 11:00    |
         | Tuesday outfit  | 2 January 2010 11:00  |
         | Monday outfit   | 1 January 2010 11:00  |
         | Another outfit  | 1 December 2009 11:00 |
    When I visit the blog "Blondinbella"
    Then I should see "March 2010" in the archive menu
     And I should see "January 2010" in the archive menu
     And I should see "December 2009" in the archive menu
     But I should not see "February 2010" in the archive menu
```

I am having a hard time figuring out the best approach for this. Should I go hardcore with a SQL-query and if so how would that look? (Using PostgreSQL)

Or is there a way of doing this smoothly just using pure Rails?

Comment: Using a SQL query would be "hardcore"?

Answer (score 2):

The pure Ruby way:

```
Post.all.group_by { |post| post.published_at.strftime("%B %Y") }.map { |group| group.first.strftime("%B %Y") }
```

Which will be a heavy load if you have a lot of posts. So you could do it in SQL:

```
Post.select("DISTINCT foo AS month").map(&:month)
```

Replace the `foo` with something to format the date (I don't know how to do this by heart, so you'll have to look that up yourself)

Answer (score 0):

With postgresql, I found using the `date_trunc` method the most useful.

eg:

```
Post.select("DISTINCT date_trunc('month', published_at) as month").collect(&:month)
```

I found it also makes sense to use the `AT TIME ZONE` construct to convert the date to your local timezone before doing the truncation:

```
Post.select("DISTINCT date_trunc('month', published_at AT TIME ZONE 'NZST') as month").collect(&:month)
```